# App Crash but there is no error in the code

Tags: java, android

I have list of items in the RecyclerView and if I click the item then it should display corresponding items. If I click the item then the app is crashing with the below message. Its not showing any error in the code. Is it a library issue? or JSON Issue? I am new to Android Development. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3 path $
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
        at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:74)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10981)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10981)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
        at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: If it crashes, there's obviously something wrong with the code... Create a [mcve]

Comment: Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 3 path $

Comment: @Kotlin please add your `.json` file.

Comment: you need to add "(maybe escaped) in front of and after keys (its always this problem if its position 3 :D)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your comments. Where do I need to add " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now I found the issue. Its due syntax error in my SQL statement where I missed e in the where condition so, its not able to fetch data. After syntax error fix then I am able to pull data without any issues. Thanks everyone for your help.